# OpenVPN forwards client's public IP

Tags: routing, openvpn

My setup is like this:

192.168.1.0/24 - server lan
192.168.3.0/24 - vpn subnet

192.168.1.11 - vpn server
192.168.1.12 - apache server

**openvpn server config**

```
local 192.168.1.11
port port_number
proto tcp
dev tun
ca /etc/openvpn/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/keys/vpnserver.crt
key /etc/openvpn/keys/vpnserver.key
dh /etc/openvpn/keys/dh.pem
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/keys/ta.key 0
server 192.168.3.0 255.255.255.0
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
tcp-nodelay
status openvpn-status.log
log-append /var/log/openvpn.log
verb 3
mute 20
client-to-client
username-as-common-name
client-cert-not-required
key-method 2
tls-server
max-clients 15
plugin /usr/lib/openvpn/openvpn-auth-ldap.so "/etc/openvpn/auth/auth-ldap.conf"
```

**openvpn client config**

```
client
remote [public_ip_of_192.168.1.11] port_number
nobind
resolv-retry infinite
proto tcp
dev tun
ca filename.crt
tls-auth filename.key 1
auth-user-pass
cipher AES-128-CBC
ns-cert-type server
persist-key
persist-tun
fast-io
pull
comp-lzo
route-method exe
route-delay 2
```

I connect to the vpn from a remote location perfectly; subnet 192.168.1.0/24 is reachable.
But, when I access apache server on 192.168.1.12, the apache log says that the request is coming from my public IP (the client's public IP).

Is it possible that apache sees the vpn IPs (192.168.3) and not each client's public one ?

Any help is appreciated !
Thanks

Comment: By 'public IP of 192.168.1.11' are you saying the machine is multi-homed, or are you connecting through a firewall with a port forward?

Comment: Windows or Linux?  If Windows, the OpenVPN client needs admin privs to be able to set the routes over the VPN interface.

Comment: @cjc I already said "subnet 192.168.1.0/24 is reachable."

Comment: @JustinP VPN is behind firewall and is being port forwarded.

Comment: Does the apache server have a return route for 192.168.3.0/24 to the openvpn box or does the openVPN box have an appropriate IPTables SNAT rule in place?

if you SSH to the apache box on the 192.168 IP then run `w` does it return your openvpn server IP?

Answer (score 1):

OK, then in my limited experience this should be working and I cannot see how you would have the external IP address appearing in the web server logs. It might be worth making absolutely sure that your TEST is working correctly. Is there any possibility that your webserver is also available via port forward through the firewall, and that you're accidentally accessing it directly - make sure you've explicitly put 192.168.1.12 IP into the browser URL for instance.

Assuming that looks OK I have found using tcpdump on the openvpn server to be a good way to watch the packets go in and out, this would confirm whether packets are leaving the openvpn server bound for the apache server with the incorrect IP address rather than somehow going there direct from the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

In general assuming all things are configured properly this shouldn't be happening.

There are however, a number of things to check and confirm here (I am assuming Linux on the server side because of TUN devices)

1. Do you have the appropriate NAT or routing configuration in place here, either:

   - A route for 192.168.3.0/24 on the apache box
   - A SNAT rule in iptables for OpenVPN server to NAT the VPN subnet to the OpenVPN server IP
2. Does your client get an actual route for 192.168.1.0/24 - does it show in your clients routing setup (`netstat -rn` for linux or `route print` for windows)
3. Does other protocol access report same IP discrepancy - e.g. running `w` on  an SSH terminal or the SSH auth log showing your login?
4. How are you accessing the website in apache - is it via the 192.168 IP or via a hostname? if its a hostname are you sure you have the DNS overridden to return the private IP instead of public?
5. Confirm that you are not using any kind of HTTP proxy that might be defeating the configuration of the VPN client by its usage

   - **Hint** - make sure the IP of your apache box is in the bypass proxy configuration
6. Which request shows the public IP? is it the initial request or additional requests for assets being requested by whatever the HTML output is? if its the latter - could it be because they are using a DNS hostname that then resolves to the public IP instead of private?

Comment: oh wow... talking about a necro.

I don't have access to this cluster anymore :D

Comment: i saw it in activity - didn't realise it was that old :D